# Is combustant a word?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology, word-formation

I am trying to pin down the definition of the word **combustant**, but I can't seem to find anything. Almost [all dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?q=combustant%20define) are giving me the definition for combustion. If I search with a strict filter, I am seeing random results for anagrams and synonyms which are not even accurate. But the word is in use, although the only place I am seeing the word used is mostly [chemistry journals, scientific books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22combustant%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks) and  oddly, [a reader's digest](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/The_Reader_s_Digest/rDI0AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22combustant%22&dq=%22combustant%22&printsec=frontcover).

So is it a valid word? Does it conform to the rules of the English language? If I were to use it in context, could I expect that a speaker of English would accept it and understand, or be able to infer, its meaning?

Comment: What does it mean?  The combustant is what is burning?  If it is a technical term in chemistry, then it would not surprising if it does not appear in standard dictionaries.

Comment: @GEdgar: "What does it mean?" - that is what I am trying to pin down. From context, it seems like either the fuel which causes combustion to happen or something which initiates the combustion.

Comment: I only know of oxidant and reductant - never heard of combustant. I checked a couple of fire-fighting glossaries and it's not in them.

Comment: Please define what "is not a valid word" means. Honest: What does that mean? Your question is fundamentally unanswerable until you define your terminology.

Comment: Thanks @cpit for updating the question.

Comment: @tchrist: The last paragraph is exactly what I mean. That if I add it to a sentence, will it be understood by a english speaker ? Would they understand what it means ?

Comment: Maybe there is no one thing that causes something to combust (catch fire),

Comment: @user96551 glad to hear the edits were in line with your intent

Comment: Doesn’t your “scientific books” link give you enough info?  “... Where hydrogen is the fuel and oxygen is the combustant...”  ?

Comment: @Jim: They do but are sometimes contradictory and contextual. I was looking for a clear cut definition. In addition, it was confusing that none of the traditional dictionaries have it mentioned.

Comment: As it's used so rarely, an intelligent Anglophone would probably be reduced to guessing what was meant (if they bothered reading on after finding the 'word' wasn't in most dictionaries, all they could access). Etically, hydrogen and oxygen burn. But calling hydrogen the fuel and oxygen the combustant needs stipulating definitions. Why not (without context) the other way round? Off-hand, I'd think that 'combustant' probably meant 'flammable', and a related noun. Antimony burns in chlorine. Which is the 'combustant' there? Is a combustant something burning and/or something that will burn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a valid word, albeit [an uncommon one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=combustant%2Ccombustants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) used primarily in specialized contexts. However, it's common enough that one of the more recent [books indexed by Google in which it occurs](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22combustant%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBy-fRo9HuAhVBVc0KHVT0B2QQpwUIJQ&biw=2100&bih=1236&dpr=1) is a [social science text](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Children_Spaces_and_Identity/iwBDCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22combustant%22&pg=PA91&printsec=frontcover) on the topic of children's learning activities. The chapter in which *combustant* appears talks about ceramics activities for children and while technical in the sense that it's an academic text, it seems oriented to readers who aren't necessarily familiar with the chemistry or physics of combustion. The paragraph where it's used begins with "From a technological point of view," and the chapter is written by archaeologists, who have specialized knowledge about the technical processes of ceramics production (which apparently involve combustants), but the authors presume their readers will be able to infer the meaning of *combustant*. The passage discusses methods of firing pottery, which involve vessels

> where fuel, combustant and vessels are partially in contact [or where] the combustant but not the fuel is in contact with the vessel.

Strangely, the word isn't listed in either the [*New Oxford Dictionary for Scientific Writers and Editors*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hGxQ0DLB24wC&source=gbs_ViewAPI) or [*A Dictionary of Chemical Engineering*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VcJ7AgAAQBAJ&source=gbs_ViewAPI)—perhaps because it's so uncommon, or because (similar to *reductant* in @Phil Sweet's comment above) the definition can be inferred from *combust* with the suffix *-ant*, which the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ant) defines as:

> agent or instrumental suffix, from Old French and French -ant, from Latin -antem, accusative of -ans, present-participle suffix of many Latin verbs.

From the above two examples, a combustant would be an agent or instrument that causes or promotes combustion—diffentiated in particular from fuel, the thing that is combustible and undergoes combustion.

---

*Updates: an uncommon word used in limited contexts.*
I asked a chemistry professor what *combustant* meant and he said he'd never heard the word before. (He noted his specialization is polymers, not fuels, but still.) After some prodding he agreed that a plausible interpretation the word, based on morphology alone and without contextual cues, would be something that promotes combustion but is not fuel.

A search within a large (~600M) institutional collection returns about 143k non-book results, more than 135k (95%) of which are patents. Around 130k (78%) of those are primarily in French. Similarly, of 3k journal articles, almost 2.6k (86%) are in French.

Comment: It is also absent from the Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: OED: “In sense the words in *‑ent, ‑ant* are primarily adjectives, sometimes distinctly participial, as *convergent, obsolescent, errant, peccant*; some, however, are, like many words of the same type in Latin and French, used as nouns (either in addition to the adjective use or exclusively), meaning (a) a personal agent, as *agent, claimant, president, regent*; (b) a material agent, as *coefficient, current, ingredient, secant, tangent, torrent*; esp. in Medicine, as *aperient, astringent, emollient, expectorant*.”

Comment: _If_ used, it needs a stipulating definition before being used. herisson's examples are using it to mean the reducing agent. Inasmuch as it _is_ used, it's ill-defined.

Answer (score 2):

> So is it a valid word? Does it conform to the rules of the English language? If I were to use it in context, could I expect that a speaker of English would accept it and understand, or be able to infer, its meaning?

There isn't a clear definition of what is or isn't a "valid" word in English. There are many processes of derivation that can create new words; some kinds of derivation can easily be applied to many words (linguists call these "productive"), while others are less common. In almost all cases, words are added to the dictionary only after they have already spread by usage outside of the dictionary.

"Combustant" has an unremarkable form for an English word. Just looking at it, an English speaker can be fairly confident that it will be pronounced /kəmˈbʌstənt/ (plus or minus some general variations between different English accents), and that it will be used as either an adjective or a noun (or both). It's also apparent that it is related to the verb *combust* and the noun *combustion.* Overall, it definitely appears to be a word.

However, I would say it is not that easy to pin down the exact meaning. It seems to have the odd quality of being mainly encountered in technical sources, while rarely being given an explicit technical definition. Some of the sources are rather old.

The ending *-ant* comes from Latin, but doesn't have a single clear meaning in English: the meaning of words ending in *-ant* can be related in various ways to other words based on the same root. So I would answer your question "If I were to use it in context, could I expect that a speaker of English would accept it and understand, or be able to infer, its meaning?" with *no*.

There are many words in English that belong to specialist vocabulary, or *jargon*: not all words have a meaning that can easily be inferred from their form or from context. The best way to understand jargon terms that are not listed in a dictionary is probably to ask a specialist.

Looking at some examples, I find some texts where *combustant* seems to refer to a combustible substance (in contrast to an oxidant, which can be another component of a fuel mix):

- > The present invention relates generally to propulsion fuels, and more particularly to propulsion monofuels employing a volatilizable **combustant** and a perchlorate compound as the oxidizing agent therefor.
- > Another object of the present invention is to provide a stable **combustant**-oxidant composition, providing a propulsion monofuel when vaporized.

(Patent publication number [US2968539A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2968539A/en), filed Aug. 31, 1950)

- > Explosion rockets without precompression of the mixture (the mixture consisting of a liquid or vaporized **combustant** and gaseous oxygen or air)

(page 12, in section "10. Propulsive Forces: General" of *[Rocket Flight Engineering](https://www.google.com/books/edition/NASA_Technical_Translation/13QjAAAAMAAJ),* by Eugen Sanger, Translation of "Raketenflugtechnik", Verlag von R. Oldenbourg, Munich and Berlin, 1933)

Comment: Is there an example of *combustant* used as an adjective? Seems like the adjectival form would be *combustible* (e.g. to qualify "material," as in your definition of *combustant*).

Comment: There's a difference between *combustible*, which means able to burn (regardless of whether burning it is a good idea), and an adjective meaning intended for use in a fire (or actually on fire). Whether *combustant* can fill the latter roles, I'm not sure.

Comment: _If_ used, it needs a stipulating definition before being used. cpit's example uses it to mean the oxidising agent. Inasmuch as it _is_ used, it's ill-defined.